# How do I make a POST request using curl?

Tags: http, curl

How do I make a [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)'s command-line tool?

Answer (score 2798):

With fields:

```bsh
curl --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

With fields specified individually:

```bsh
curl --data "param1=value1" --data "param2=value2" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

[Multipart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request/19712083#19712083):

```bsh
curl --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt" https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

Multipart with fields and a filename:

```bsh
curl --form "fileupload=@my-file.txt;filename=desired-filename.txt" --form param1=value1 --form param2=value2 https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

Without data:

```bsh
curl --data '' https://example.com/resource.cgi
    
curl -X POST https://example.com/resource.cgi

curl --request POST https://example.com/resource.cgi
```

See the [cURL manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) for more information. The [cURL tutorial on HTTP Scripting](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) is also helpful for emulating a web browser.

With `libcurl`, use the `curl_formadd()` function to build your form before submitting it in the usual way.  See the [libcurl documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) for more information.

For large files, consider adding parameters to show upload progress:

```bsh
curl --tr-encoding -X POST -v -# -o output -T filename.dat \
      http://example.com/resource.cgi
```

The `-o output` is required, otherwise, no progress bar will appear.

Comment: @LauriRanta `--data-urlencode` (no dash), in recent versions at least

Comment: Also works if you need to update a resource with a PUT: curl -X PUT ...

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding... when would I do it `With Fields`, when with `Multipart` and when `Without Data`?

Comment: Instead of `--data` you can use `-d`.

Comment: i have an array of fields. how can i do this?

Comment: @ARUNBALANNV convert them into a string first with `implode`

Comment: Worth noting you can provide a json array to `-d` like `-d '{"param1":value1", "param2":"value2"}'` as long as you also include `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Answer (score 556):

For a RESTful HTTP POST containing XML:

> `curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/path/to/resource --header "Content-Type:text/xml"`

or for JSON, use this:

> `curl -X POST -d @filename.txt http://example.com/path/to/resource --header "Content-Type:application/json"`

This will read the contents of the file named `filename.txt` and send it as the post request.

Comment: @tom-wijsman explanation: `curl -X POST` implies an HTTP POST request, the `-d` parameter (long version: `--data`) tells curl that what follows will be POST parameters, and `@filename` designates the contents of the file `filename` as parameter. This approach works best with RESTful HTTP APIs as found at Twitter, Facebook, various other web services including Ruby on Rails as well as HTTP APIs of databases such as CouchDB. REST stands for [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST)

Comment: How can we see response xml not in one line but formatted?

Comment: I think that you can leave off the `-X POST` since that is implied by `-d`.

Comment: How to give multiple headers?

Comment: Multiple Headers: curl -H "header2:1" -H "header2:2" ...

Comment: Or do `-d 'JSON_STRING'` for inline JSON instead of reading it from a file.

Answer (score 164):

**Data from stdin with `-d @-`**

Example:

```
echo '{"text": "Hello **world**!"}' | curl -d @- https://api.github.com/markdown
```

Output:

```
<p>Hello <strong>world</strong>!</p>
```

Comment: Great if you have a JSON object already in clipboard

Comment: even better: echo "$message" | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d @- "$url"

Answer (score 78):

```
curl -d "name=Rafael%20Sagula&phone=3320780" http://www.where.com/guest.cgi
```

is the example found in the [**Curl Example Manual**](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d).

Use %26 for the ampersands though if the above doesn't work:

```
curl -d "name=Rafael%20Sagula%26phone=3320780" http://www.where.com/guest.cgi
```

Answer (score 70):

If you want to login to a site, do the following:

```
curl -d "username=admin&password=admin&submit=Login" --dump-header headers http://localhost/Login
curl -L -b headers http://localhost/
```

The first request saves the session cookie (that is provided upon successful login) in the "headers" file. From now on you can use that cookie to authenticate you to any part of the website that you usually access after logging in with a browser.

Comment: a note from curl's man page: 'The -c, --cookie-jar option is however a better way to store cookies.'

Answer (score 48):

If you are lazy, you can get google-chrome or firefox to do all the work for you.

1. Right-click the form you want to submit and select **Inspect** (or ***Inspect Element*** for Firefox). This will open the DevTools panel.
2. Select the **Network** tab in devtools and tick the  **Preserve log** checkbox (***Persist Logs*** for firefox).
3. Submit the form and locate the entry with method POST (right-click on any column header and make sure **Method** is checked).
4. Right click the line with POST, and select **Copy** > **Copy as cURL**.

[image: chrome devtools: copy as cURL]

Chrome will copy all the request data in cURL syntax.

Chrome uses `--data 'param1=hello&param2=world'` which you can make more readable by using a single `-d` or `-F` per parameter depending on which type of POST request you want to send, which can be either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` accordingly.

This will be POST-ed as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (*used for the majority of forms that don't contain file uploads*):

```bash
curl http://httpbin.org/post \
    -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/2.2" \
    -d param1=hello \
    -d name=dinsdale
```

For a `multipart/form-data` POST use `-F` (*typically used with forms that contain file uploads, or where order of fields is important, or where multiple fields with the same name are required*):

```bash
curl http://httpbin.org/post \
    -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/2.2" \
    -F param1=hello \
    -F name=dinsdale \
    -F name=piranha
```

<sup>The `User-Agent` header is not normally needed, but I've thrown it in just in case. If you need a custom agent then you can avoid having to set it on every request by creating the `~/.curlrc` file which contains e.g. `User-Agent: "Mozilla/2.2"`</sup>

Answer (score 39):

```
curl -v --data-ascii var=value http://example.com
```

and there are many more options, check `curl --help` for more information.