# A way to paste predefined list of text in bash script to browser?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell-script

I am looking for a way in bash to paste a few lines (which will be selected in a loop) to a form on a webpage at a certain location (i.e to a specific field on a page).  Is this possible?  Hope I've made sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out curl (http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). It offers numerous possibilities to access the web through the command line (including POST requests).

Also take a look at [What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

Comment: Alternatively you could use `wget` to send a POST request.