# Need program to brute force

Tags: brute-force

we have written an application which involves user and id parameters. We would like to test the app with brute force attack, where login is known, and password is max 6 characters. 
Is there any "testing" program available over the internet to conduct such a proccess?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? How exactly do you want to test? What is "application"? A web (HTTP) app or something else?

Comment: Application is on web, we finnally have used ZAP Attack Proxy

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extensively test your application, you should take a look at a Linux distro called Kali. It has all the tools required for pentest and application attacks. A tool that is provided and could help you is Hydra.

You can get it here: https://www.offensive-security.com/

Comment: Backtrack's no longer maintained. It's now Kali, http://www.kali.org/

Answer (score 0):

cURL is your friend.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

[What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)