# understanding sending post request (with curl)

Tags: command-line, terminal, html, curl

alright, I know related questions have been answered :

[What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978411/http-post-and-get-using-curl-in-linux

but my question is rather more basic,

Supposedly we have the following `form` in a `html` page:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
<h3>echo your name:</h3>
<input id="myname" name="myname" type="text" value="nafas">
<input type="image" src="/img/verifyName"  onclick="progress(true)">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write('<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById(\'myname\').value=\'\';return false">Clear Field</'+'a>')</script>
</form>
```

Once botton is clicked , it basically  echos what ever is typed in the text box

So my question is how exactly do the same thing with "`curl`".
what do I need to echo my name?

server is running locally. I can't provide the link. but let's say its running at `http://www.example.com`

**EDIT 1 :**

this is how progress Function look like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function progress(s){var o=document.getElementById("myname");if(o){if(s){o.style.backgroundImage="url(/img/progress.gif)";o.style.backgroundPosition="right center";
o.style.backgroundRepeat="no-repeat";}else{o.style.backgroundImage="none";}}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In that form you provided, its Javascript that calls the function `progress()` and that function echoes the value.

There is no URL to send the value via post. Since it is handled via Javascript, whether `curl` nor `wget` can send the form for you.

Comment: well there gotta be something that is sending that infromation. are you saying there is no way to mimic that behaviour?

Comment: Thats the clue: nothing is sended. Javascript just prints the value to you. No client server interaction has occured.

Comment: Oh I c, that means on the click, we don't send request to server as  it is computed on local machine.

Comment: Exactly, javascript is executed in your browser.

Comment: right, apologies for my ignorance here. I disconnected computer from the internet, then clicked on the botton. I was expecting to get some results since there is no need of the host no more. by my surprise  it is getting me "page not found" . so if I don't deal with the server no more, y does it care I need internet connection?

Comment: Then we have to know what exactly the `progress()` function does, you have to post that javascript part. Javascript can also request a new page.

Comment: just edited the question mate, I've added the progress(s) funcntion

Comment: It unfortunately changes nothing; no client server interaction, except the picture `/img/progress.gif`, the "page not found" error may come from that.

Comment: well thanks alot mate, u gave quite nice knowledge