# Escaping asterisk * in Bash on Windows

Tags: bash, msysgit, escape-characters, msys

The following command works in GNU Bash on FreeBSD but not in [Git Bash](https://msysgit.github.io/) on Windows:

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"'
```

The intended result is to send a `PUT` request to `https://example.com/_config/cors/origins` with the body `"*"` (including the quotes - it's a JSON string).

However on Windows, the asterisk gets expanded as a glob even though it’s within quotes. Excerpt from `--trace-ascii` cURL log:

```
0000: PUT /_config/cors/origins HTTP/1.1
004f: User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
008e: Content-Length: 13
00a2: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00d3: 
=> Send data, 13 bytes (0xd)
0000: .editorconfig
== Info: upload completely sent off: 13 out of 13 bytes
```

(`.editorconfig` is the first file in the current directory.)

Escaping with a backslash (`'"\*"'`) transmits the backslash:

```
0000: PUT /_config/cors/origins HTTP/1.1
004f: User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
008e: Content-Length: 4
00a1: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00d2: 
=> Send data, 4 bytes (0x4)
0000: "\*"
== Info: upload completely sent off: 4 out of 4 bytes
```

Two backslashes also transmits both backslashes in the request.

```
0000: PUT /_config/cors/origins HTTP/1.1
004f: User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
008e: Content-Length: 5
00a1: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00d2: 
=> Send data, 5 bytes (0x5)
0000: "\\*"
== Info: upload completely sent off: 5 out of 5 bytes
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you sure bash is the culprit and not curl? What curl are you using (native build or cygwin/msys one)? Some versions of libc for Windows will expand * (but not other globs) while parsing the command line (from `GetCommandLine` to argc/argv) -> can you test with cmd.exe (that passes the command line unchanged) if you can also see the "globbing"?

Comment: When using a `cmd` prompt I can get it to work by passing `-d \"*\"`

Comment: and when you try `-d '\"*\"'` in bash, it does not work?

Comment: nope, it sends the backslashes too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this idea based on [escaping tips and ideas found on this site](http://qntm.org/bash):

```
curl -X PUT https://example.com/_config/cors/origins -d "\*"
```

Another idea comes [from this answer on a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/255624/167207) about sending data via a POST request. First create a “data” file called “data.txt” that simply contains the `*`. Then run this `curl` command:

```
curl -X POST -d @data.txt https://example.com/_config/cors/origins
```

You could try that without the `-X POST` which sets the request method like this:

```
curl -d @data.txt https://example.com/_config/cors/origins
```