# How do I do an HTTP POST to a server living in an Amazon ec2 instance over ssh?

Tags: ssh, http, amazon-ec2, api

I have a server listening on http://0.0.0.0:8000, however this is living in an Amazon instance.

How can I make an HTTP POST request from an external computer (using `curl`)?
That is, I would like to use the server listening as an API. This is different from other cases because I would like to do it over ssh.

Comment: Thanks for the help Attie, yes that's what I meant

Comment: "_listening on `0.0.0.0:8000`_" means "_listening on all interfaces_" - so can you communicate with it on it's public IP? (the same you would use for SSH)

Comment: Yes I think so Attie, when I start the server it just says: `no port specified, defaulting to port 8000` that lives in the ec2 instance. I would like to do the `curl -XPOST` from an "external machine"

Comment: I presume you are able to use SSH? Have you tried using `curl` with the same IP you used for SSH?

Comment: No, could you provide an example attie?

Comment: How are you managing the EC2 instance? SSH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cURL command-line syntax to do a POST request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

Comment: Its different because I would like to do it over ssh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `curl` **on** the EC2 instance, and tunnel the output via `ssh`, then try the following:

```
ssh ${USERNAME}@${EC2_INSTANCE_IP} curl -s http://localhost:8000/
```

You should see the result directly on the terminal (`-s` will inhibit `curl`'s output).

You can run any command like this, there's nothing special for `curl`.

If this works, then you can alter the `curl` parameters to use `-X POST` and/or `-d`, along with the correct endpoint.

---

Please remember though, that `0.0.0.0` is a "*special*" address that actually means "*listening on **all** interfaces*"... So unless you configure the inbound rules correctly, anyone can still do `curl http://${EC2_INSTANCE_IP}:8000/` and hit your server.

Comment: Do you have a reference on how to configure this on the amazon instance? I got a Failed to connect to the instance, timed out

Comment: You might like to ask another question, specifically around inbound rules for EC2... get the basic SSH working first, and then come back and try to "_use `curl` over SSH_" afterwards.

Comment: This link might help: [Authorizing Inbound Traffic for Your Linux Instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html)